# How to embed a search result on a node?

Tags: views, search

I am looking for a while to include a search results on a node.

Let me explain:

Administrator side, i wish i could, when i create a node, enter search criteria (eg "home + garden"-cellar), which generates me, when viewing the node, a list of nodes matching these criteria.

It will give : The title of my node, body, and below the result of my research.

I do not know if this is clear, but how could I do that?

I'm using Search API on my site, i should programmatically execute a search in the index from keywords ... but I'm stuck on this point.

Thank you in advance!
Joel.

Answer (score 0):

So, I will create my own module to do that. The module will offer a new field can be created on any type of content, and will accept search criterias, the number to display, and so a search result will appear in the node.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal's core Search module should be enough for what you want to achieve. But in case you need more information about Search in Drupal [this](http://poplarware.com/articles/drupal_search) article should help you out.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I will use Drupal's core search module. But at the moment, I can't find how to limit search results when using search_data or search_execute...The limit is ahrd-coded to 10. Is there a way to dynamically change this value ?